# How to get inAppBrowser Close event after redirect another local html page..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm integrating cordova inAppBrowser Plugin in my project, but I'm getting some Issue.

how to get inAppBrowser close event on my ajax success in my 2nd html page.

Here is my 1st html page code,

```
<input type="button" id="pay" value="PAY"></input>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $( document ).ready(function() {

          $("#pay").click(function()
          {
               var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("page2.html", "_blank", "location=yes");
          });

     });

<script>
```

Here is my 2nd html page code,

```
     $( document ).ready(function() {

          $.ajax({
                url: url + "EmailVerified?Email=" + $("#email").val() + "&Amount=" + RechargeValue,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: true,
                async: true,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    //Here i want to close my inAppBrowser window is it Possible..?
                }
          });    

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ref.addEventListener('exit', onResume);
```

Then create a function onResume to handle what to do next.

Comment: I already try but this function not working because its my second page so ref is not defined.

Comment: Opening a page inside of cordova should act exactly like your primary page, which means the javascript needs to be loaded exactly the same as well.  For instance, window.location = 'page2.html' should open the page like it did the initial html.  But you will need to refire the device ready listener and add document.addEventListener('exit', onResume);